# PhoneGap Opening a PDF error "document could not be opened"

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, pdf

I am currently using PhoneGap. I am using eclipse as my IDE. The tablet that I am developing on is a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, android version 4.0.4.

Now I am trying to open a PDF on the device through my app. However it is not working. I followed the tutorial on this page, https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener.

Here are the changes I have made.

-> In the src folder, I made a new folder called com.phonegap.plugins.fileopener -> I copied and pasted the FileOpener.java file into the folder. -> Then in the config.xml file located in the xml folder, I added the line

```
<plugin name="FileOpener" value="com.phonegap.plugins.fileopener.FileOpener"/>
```

-> I also added the line

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="fileopener.js"></script>
```

into my index.html file

Here is the code for index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> PhoneGap </title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="fileopener.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>PDF Open Tester</h1>
        <a href="#" onclick="window.plugins.fileOpener,open('/sdcard/Course Content Files/1.pdf');">open</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just as further information, once I have connected the tablet on my computer, when I right click on 1.pdf and check properties the file location is Computer\GT-P7510\Tablet

When I run this project on the tablet and click on the open link. The adobe reader app opens up on the home page saying "The document could not be opened". What is going wrong why is the pdf not opening with Adobe Reader? Please help if you can I would really appreciate it.

-----------------------------------After Edit 1-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I found the specfic error that is happening. The error is Object # has no method 'exec'

Comment: In general it is bad practice to hardcode `/sdcard/` into your file paths. In java you'd use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. I don't know if there is an equivalent to that in phonegap or not. But my guess is that your device does not label its external storage as `/sdcard/` so you are trying to have it load a file that isn't there.

Comment: I thoguth getExternalStorageDirectory() was only for appcelerator.

Comment: No, it is part of the Java APIs, appcelerator may use it (I don't know though, no experience with anything but native.) It looks like from the example on the github page you linked that you may need to prepend your file path with `file://` though so you might try changing the url to `file:///sdcard/Course Content Files/1.pdf` note that even if this does work on your device it will still fail on some due to the external dir not being located at a `/sdcard/` which is why the Environment API exists so that you app doesn't have to care where it is located.

Comment: ok so basically I should replace /sdcard/ with /Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory/?

Comment: IT WORKED REPLACING IT WITH file:///, I LOVEEEEE YOUUUU. I've been trying to do this for sooooooo long. Gave up a few times. OH LORD THANK YOU!

Comment: also as a side note should I replace /sdcard/ with /Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory/?

Comment: no, `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is a Java method call. If you put that into your html it will just break things. Ultimately though you should strive to learn a little bit of Java and the Android APIs, even if you continue to develop on phonegap it will be helpful to you because you can make your own plugins if need be. (which is what you would have to do in order to take advantage of the `Environment` API)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FileOpener pluggin is expecting a URI, and you are passing it a filepath.

change:

```
'/sdcard/Course Content Files/1.pdf'
```

to:

```
'file:///sdcard/Course Content Files/1.pdf'
```